# creating objects with same name as class in java

Tags: java, c++, object, constructor

In C++ when I create an object like the following, then no more objects can be created for the same class.

```
Box Box; //Box is the class Name
```

Here Box becomes an object and whenever we use `Box` again the compiler recognizes it as an object. But in the case of java this isn't.

```
Box Box = new Box(); 
Box box = new Box(); //valid
```

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Do you mean that you can't create more than one object of a class in C++? Like: `Box Box; Box box;`?

Comment: Yes in c++ we cant create any more instances.

Comment: `Box Box` means you are *defining a reference*, it doesn't *create an object*.

Comment: But you *can* create more instances. `class Box b;` or `struct Box b;`. Anyway, what are you really asking?

Comment: I remember this wasn't allowed in Java 6, you got the error that `Box` does not name a type back then. I don't know why it is allowed today

Comment: Thats is the way these 2 languages are written. You cant ask why java is called java and why c++ is not called java!

Comment: Just because c++ has this quirky design detail, why would Java inherit this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, Java has slightly different set of syntax rules, by the sounds of it. When the grammar says you've got a variable declaration with an initializer, such as this:

```
Box box = new Box();
```

... it knows that `Box` has to be the name of a type, not the name of a variable. So it doesn't matter whether or not there's a variable called `Box` in scope. (That applies to the `new` operator as well.)

I don't know the intimate details of the C++ syntax, but it sounds like it's not set up to make that distinction, at least in the example you've given. It's not like it's a *feature* as such - it's just a matter of how names are looked up by the compiler.

Comment: I suspect you _could_ do this if you didn't import the `Box` type.  i.e. `com.something.Box Box = new com.something.Box()`. Right?

Answer (score 5):

Java is using different namespaces for different types of identifiers.  The restricted syntax of Java makes it unambiguous whether you are referring to a type, a function, a variable or a label.

Answer (score 2):

For details about how a name lookup works in C++ see section 3.4 in the standard.

In the case you described the basic idea is this: for an unqualified name (like Box your code), the compiler starts searching for a declaration in the current scope before moving up. When it finds a declaration for that name, any declaration, it stops.
So in your case, when you try to declare a new variable of type Box, it finds the declaration of the variable 'Box' and stops searching. It just assumes that 'Box' is a variable name and doesn't look any further.